# OpenGL - How does texturing affect shadows/lightning?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

So the question is: when I switch from ColorPointers to Textures, it seems that the lightning/shadows effects are greatly reduced. Some solution that I have found but doesnt do that much is setting glLightModeli( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR ). Is there anything more I could do to get closer effects to what I would get without textures?

This is how I init my lights/scene:

```
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);                       # Black Background
    glClearDepth (1.0);                                      # Depth Buffer Setup
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)                                   # The Type Of Depth Testing 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                                
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                                 # Select Smooth Shading       
    glColor4f(0.90, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)   
    #glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, 0)  
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);        
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, [0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 30)
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);    
    glLightModeli( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR );
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, [0.85, 0.8, 0.75, 0])
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0])
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0])
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0])
```

And for the actual drawing.

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)         
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferVertices)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)          
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferNormals)
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, None)           
    #glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
    #glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)        
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferTextureIndex)
    glTexCoordPointer(1, GL_FLOAT, 0, None);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(self.triangles) , GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ADT.voidDataPointer(self.triangles))
```

For the colors of each vertex I was using the normals as dummy colors, since that was just a step in the way of integrating textures. The texture is a self generated one , basically the values are from:

```
   def getColor(self, value):
    if value < 0:
        return [1, 0, 0]
    if value >=0 and value < 0.8:
        return [1, 0.5, 0]
    if value >= 0.8 and value < 1:
        return [1, 1, 0]
    if value >=1 and value < 1.2:
        return [0.5, 1, 0]
    if value >=1.2 and value < 1.4:
        return [0, 1, 0]
    if value >= 1.4 and value < 1.6:
        return [0, 1, 0.5]
    if value >= 1.6 and value < 1.8:
        return [0, 1, 1]
    if value >= 1.8 and value < 2:
        return [0, 0.5, 1]
    if value >= 2:
        return [0, 0, 1]
```

The actual creation:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 190, 0, GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT, textureArray)
```

Regards,
Bogdan

**EDIT**

Ok I got close to the effect I wanted but it was purely by trying different combinations of glColor4f with materials and ligths in the following part.

```
    glColor4f(2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 1.0)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)   
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, 0)  
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)        
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 30)
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)    
    glLightModeli( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR )
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, [0, -10, -400, 0])
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0, 0, 0, 0])
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0])
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0])
```

Is there some kind of formula of how all of these (glColor4f + Materials + Lights + Texture) influence the final color/shadow/shininess effects ?

Comment: Vertex Colors, the stuff you set with glColorPointer, are something entirely different than textures. You can't replace the one with another. Textures are like images you strech/fit onto a face, whereas vertex colours are just colours at the vertices itself that are blended into a gradient over the face.

Comment: I think we need more information here. Do you use some middleware ? How do you light your scene ? And, also, are the colors in your texture as "bright" as the ones you specify with colorpointer ?

Comment: Well, what would work is using a 1D texture as a vertex colour lookup table in a **vertex** shader. Using that the behaviour would be the same like using a vertex colour buffer. However it's probably easier and also more performant to just use a Vertex Buffer Object for the vertex colour array.

Comment: Could you link screen shots exemplifying exactly what you mean? It might be that the color blend mode and the texture blend mode are different from what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your shader in your other question here [OpenGL shaders questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276965/glshaders-questions)

then the answer is that you are not handling lighting in your shader which disables the fixed function lighting routines when you enable your shader.

If I am jumping the gun on this conclusion and you are seeing thing without the shader, I apologize.

### Edit

Yes, there is a formula. It is covered extensively in the orange book and briefly in the red book http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html. Older version are freely available of the red, book.

Basically it depends on the texture of the object, if there is a color and how it is applied, modulated, added, multiplied. The material and how it reflects lights of different colors, plus any emisions the material makes ( think glow in the dark sticker material for emission ), and the color of the light and the angle the light is striking the face. "Shiny" comes from specular reflection of light.

Comment: No, I abandoned the Shader approach as I cannot find the reason it drops performance so bad. This was just a texture approach. Seems like the problem was the materials/colors I was using. I'll update my post shortly.